# Unable to deploy firebase functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Whenever i'm running "firebase deploy --only functions" it hits up with this error
 Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

> TypeError: functions.https.onCall(...).then is not a function
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Firebase Revision\functions\index.js:11:4)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
>       at C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:15:15
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:53:3)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)

Following is my code in index.js functions

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addAdminRole = functions.https.onCall((data,context) => {
    return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email).then(user => {
        return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid,{
            admin: true
        });
    })
}).then(()=>{
    return {
        message: `Success! ${data.email} has been made an admin`
    }
}).catch(err => {
    return err;
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't chain the `then()` method correctly. You should do as follows:

```
exports.addAdminRole = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email)
        .then(user => {
            return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
                admin: true
            });
        })
        .then(() => {
            return {
                message: `Success! ${data.email} has been made an admin`
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            return err;
        })
})
```

---

Note that instead of doing

```
.catch(err => {
    return err;
})
```

you should follow the doc on [how to handle errors in a Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors).